# What would be correct form for "Good luck on keep supporting your toxic partner"?

Tags: prepositions

The continuous tense after the proposition seems incorrect to me. It has a better form but what is it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to say.

Comment: I would suggest using a less negative example sentence. That being said, it's not 100% clear what you're actually asking. Please edit your question to address both issues.

Comment: @HotLicks I wanted to say something like I am tired of listening to her illogical arguments on a third person. So I am saying out of anger that I am over with it.

Comment: @CJDennis The context was too negative I know. How about - "Good luck on continuing your hardworks."

Comment: Yes, that removes the sarcasm. It should be "hard work" though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to say, "Good luck continuing to support your toxic partner."

Comment: I think you are right.